# Hibernate: How to represent this type of relation

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to add hibernate on legacy DB. I have schema like below.

```
       X_Table
+--------+-----------+
| number |  class_id |
+--------+-----------+
|      1 |  c1       |
|      1 |  c2       |
|      1 |  c3       |
|      2 |  c2       |
|      2 |  c4       |
|      3 |  c4       |
|      4 |  c5       |
+--------+-----------+


                   Y_Table
+----+-------------+-------------+------------+
| id |  class_id_1 |  class_id_2 |  other_col |
+----+-------------+-------------+------------+
|  1 | c1          | c2          |  value1    |
|  2 | c1          | c3          |  value1    |
|  3 | c2          | c3          |  value1    |
|  4 | c3          | c5          |  value1    |
|  5 | c3          | c4          |  value1    |
+----+-------------+-------------+------------+
```

**How to map these table in Hibernate?**

Here's a current query that is used to get the data

```
SELECT *
FROM Y_Table AS Y
    LEFT OUTER JOIN X_Table AS X
        ON Y.class_id_1 = X.class_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN X_Table AS X2
        ON Y.class_id_2 = X2.class_id
```

Comment: This looks like a many-to-many relationship between `X` and `Y`.  Just Google around for "Hibernate many to many" and you will see how to structure your Java classes.

Comment: When used ManyToMany it tries to add the relation with Y_Table.id but in my case relation is maintained by Y_Table.class_id_*

Comment: Not sure that I follow you, though your data does really seem to imply a many to many relationship.